# Hide specific div if opened by clicking on its own link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 3 divs that open which work fine. I need to be able to close the current div that is opened if the corresponding link is clicked so no divs are opened.

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/gu5b3mk1/1/

html:

```
<ul>
   <li><a id="category" href="">Catergory</a></li>
        <li><a id="style" href="">styles</a></li>
        <li><a id="brand" href="">brand</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="one">This is my category</div>
    <div id="two">This is styles</div>
    <div id="three">This is main brands</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#category").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').hide();
  $("#one").fadeToggle();
});

$("#style").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $('div').hide();
  $("#two").fadeToggle();
});
$("#brand").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $('div').hide();
  $("#three").fadeToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
#two, #three, #four{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your function to:

```
$("#category").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#two,#three').hide();
  $("#one").fadeToggle();
});

$("#style").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $('#one,#three').hide();
  $("#two").fadeToggle();
});
$("#brand").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $('#one,#two').hide();
  $("#three").fadeToggle();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/gu5b3mk1/2/).

[EDIT]
As an alternative you could use this code, it's a more flexible, also when you add new items to your menu. It uses the `id` of the anchor and shows the corresponding `div_id`.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a id="category" href="">Catergory</a></li>
    <li><a id="style" href="">styles</a></li>
    <li><a id="brand" href="">brand</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="div_category">This is my category</div>
<div id="div_style">This is styles</div>
<div id="div_brand">This is main brands</div>
```

```
$("#list li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = '#div_'+$(this).attr('id');
    $('div:not('+div+')').hide();
    $(div).fadeToggle();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/gu5b3mk1/5/).